# Keep alpine container running but handle SIGTERM gracefully

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

For testing purposes I'm starting a alpine container using `docker-compose` like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  alpine:
    image: alpine:3.7.3
    container_name: compose_test_alpine
```

I want to keep the container running in the background, so I'm using this `command` for the `alpine` `service`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  alpine:
    image: alpine:3.7.3
    command: 'tail -f /dev/null'
    container_name: compose_test_alpine
```

When calling `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose kill` now I get a [non zero exit code](https://success.docker.com/article/what-causes-a-container-to-exit-with-code-137):

```
compose_test_alpine exited with code 137
```

Is there a simple way by means of using a shell script to handle the shutdown gracefully resulting in exit code `0`?

Comment: What does the container _do_?  Running a bare `alpine` container usually isn't that interesting; if it's not running any process in particular, why do you not want it to exit?

Comment: It is part of a automated testing scenario where we need to ensure containers get stopped / killed properly. We could have also used e.g. a MongoDb container (indeed, we did this before), but we wanted to keep this image size small in CI.